# How to launch a Gazebo node with a namespace in ROS2?

Tags: python, ros2, gazebo-simu

I want to launch in a python launch file a gazebo node with a namespace.

Something like:
`<namespace>/gazebo`

With the namespace matching my other nodes.

I want all of the nodes I'm launching with the same unique namespace so that others on the same network as me can know which nodes are from whom.

For now, I am launching gazebo with an execute process in my launch file:

```
ld.add_action(
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=["gazebo", "--verbose", "-s", "libgazebo_ros_factory.so", "src/robokicks_simulation/worlds/empty.world"],
            output="screen",
    )
)
```

And the 'ros2 node list' returns

```
/gazebo
/<namespace>/joint_state_publisher
/<namespace>/robot_state_publisher
```